# Hash Byte array with given salt Byte array using SHA1 in UWP

Tags: java, c#, .net, cryptography, win-universal-app

I have a randomly generated `byte` array :

```
Random random = new Random();
var bytes = new byte[32];
random.NextBytes(myBytes);
```

And I want to hash it using `SHA1` with a given byte array like for example :

```
public static readonly sbyte[] salt = new sbyte [] { 82, 122,   43,  30,
                                                          -47,  97,    4,-124,
                                                          -31, -63, -108,  69,
                                                          -83, -86, -125,  88,
                                                          -98, -77,  111,  79,
                                                          -71, -73,  100, 106,
                                                           8, -20,  -95, -27,
                                                          38, -32,  -61,  88};
```

I'm not really experienced with this, I have this `java` code that I want to write in `C#` on `UWP` platform:

```
public static byte []computeKey(byte[] bytes) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException 
{
     byte[] salt = { 82,122, 43, 30,-47, 97, 4,-124,-31,-63,-108, 69,-83,-86,-125, 88,-98,-77,111, 79,-71,-73,100,106,  8,-20,-95,-27, 38,-32,-61, 88};
     MessageDigest digester = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
     digester.update(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
     digester.update(salt, 0, salt.length);
     byte[] digest = digester.digest();
     return digest;
}
```

I want to achieve this in C# UWP, I could find that it is doable in `.Net` using the `System.Security.Cryptography` using the `TransformBlock` method (not sure though exactly how), the problem is that on UWP it's totally different, using `Windows.Security.Cryptography`, there's not too much choices offered, tried some paths but nothing was clear, any hints how this can be achieved ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
byte[] salt = { 82, 122, 43, 30, 47, 97, 4, 124, 31, 63, 108, 69, 83, 86, 125, 88, 98, 77, 111, 79, 71, 73, 100, 106, 8, 20, 95, 27, 38, 32, 61, 88 };
var message = "message";
var computedBytes = HmacSha1Sign(salt, message);
```

with this function:

```
public static byte[] HmacSha1Sign(byte[] keyBytes, string message)
{
    var messageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
    MacAlgorithmProvider objMacProv = MacAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm("HMAC_SHA1");
    CryptographicKey hmacKey = objMacProv.CreateKey(keyBytes.AsBuffer());
    IBuffer buffHMAC = CryptographicEngine.Sign(hmacKey, messageBytes.AsBuffer());
    return buffHMAC.ToArray();
}
```